# Install Certificate InstallCert.java failed

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I had installed the InstallCert.java but failed. The error show "Error: Could not find or load main class InstallCert.java". I already added java path but still an error when I ran "java InstallCert.java localhost:8080" in command prompt. one question also, what the choosen port? 8080 or the https port? I am using JBOSS EAP 6.4. How to solved this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the .java extension. First compile it using `javac InstallCert.java`, then use java to run it: `java InstallCert localhost:8080`

`java` only runs class files (.class), not source files (.java), so you need to compile them first with `javac`. And even then, the java executable does not require the .class extension.

More elaborate instructions found here: https://github.com/jkandasa/resource/wiki/Adding-a-Certificate-into-the-Java-Certificate-Store

Comment: If you are having the same error, you haven't read the instructions. Do not run the java file, instead compile it and run the compiled one.

Comment: the error show read time out.. which port I use? https port? I running with localhost:8080, and I think its http port, when I run the service, show error about certificate. any solution?

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please mark it as an answer. You are now describing a new problem based on the fixed previous one. And you *think* it's the HTTP port? 8080 sounds like HTTP, and yes, if you need to install the certificate, use the HTTPS port. (8443?) Remember we don't have a crystal ball here.